# Prevent cron job from running on reboot

Tags: centos, cron

I have a script that is set to run after reboot with `@reboot`. There is a problem with the script and crashing the system as soon as it boot up. Is there away to prevent the job from running?

Comment: Comment it out or remove it. This isn't difficult.

Comment: That is assuming I can log in, but now I can't. It will just crash the system and shut it down as soon as it boot up

Comment: Read up on single user mode. You can log in that way to comment or delete the cronjob.

Comment: Thank you. single user mode did the trick.

Comment: @hugoleung I think you should answer your own question with what was done or delete your question, since it appears there's no answer needed anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Following Nasir Riley's suggest, boot into single user mode and delete the cronjob